# Why can't I import CFEVideoConf and image_resize from utils module in Python 3.7.2

Tags: python, python-import

I learn from the Internet that using timelaspe to capture images. However, I got some problem. I saw from GitHub and many people can use :
`from utils import CFEVideoConf, image_resize` but I cannot. I did it in SublimeText 3.0... If somebody know that problem, please help me. Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```py
from utils import CFEVideoConf, image_resize
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'CFEVideoConf' from 'utils' (C:\Users\NGHIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\utils__init__.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say *'many people'* you probably refer to [this](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/OpenCV-Python-Series) repository.

That is the only person who defined `CFEVideoConf` that I could find.
This is [the definition for that class](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/OpenCV-Python-Series/blob/master/src/utils.py#L34):

```
class CFEVideoConf(object):
    # Standard Video Dimensions Sizes
    STD_DIMENSIONS =  {
        "360p": (480, 360),
        "480p": (640, 480),
        "720p": (1280, 720),
        "1080p": (1920, 1080),
        "4k": (3840, 2160),
    }
    # Video Encoding, might require additional installs
    # Types of Codes: http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php
    VIDEO_TYPE = {
        'avi': cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'),
        #'mp4': cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264'),
        'mp4': cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'),
    }

    width           = 640
    height          = 480
    dims            = (640, 480)
    capture         = None
    video_type      = None
    def __init__(self, capture, filepath, res="480p", *args, **kwargs):
        self.capture = capture
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.width, self.height = self.get_dims(res=res)
        self.video_type = self.get_video_type()

    # Set resolution for the video capture
    # Function adapted from https://kirr.co/0l6qmh
    def change_res(self, width, height):
        self.capture.set(3, width)
        self.capture.set(4, height)

    def get_dims(self, res='480p'):
        width, height = self.STD_DIMENSIONS['480p']
        if res in self.STD_DIMENSIONS:
            width, height = self.STD_DIMENSIONS[res]
        self.change_res(width, height)
        self.dims = (width, height)
        return width, height

    def get_video_type(self):
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(self.filepath)
        if ext in self.VIDEO_TYPE:
          return  self.VIDEO_TYPE[ext]
        return self.VIDEO_TYPE['avi']
```

And indeed, he has multiple files in which he imports that class. For example, [here](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/OpenCV-Python-Series/blob/master/src/lessons/timelapse-how-to.py).

In order to make it work on **your** environment, you need to:

1. **clone the repository** locally:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/OpenCV-Python-Series
   ```
2. Install the requirements:

   ```
   cd OpenCV-Python-Series
   pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```
3. And then you can fully use the project

Answer (score 0):

Copy the "***utils.py***" file from [here](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/OpenCV-Python-Series/tree/master/src) and put it in the working directory.